# Display only image post from Tumblr blog in android app

Tags: android, json, oauth

I'm making an app that will display pictures using a RecyclerView with a staggered layout. I want to pull the images from a tumblr blog an implement them in the recyclerView. I have already registered my app and received the the OAuth Consumer Key and the Secret Key. Now, I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to implement this code into the recyclerView I have setup. This is all I want to accomplish. Just have the images displayed on the app. No login is required. Not much functionality, just display the pictures.

I'm given this when I chose the OAuth Authentication option

```
// Authenticate via OAuth
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("key");
client.setToken("key");

// Make the request
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("type", "photo");
List<Post> posts = client.blogPosts("url", params);
```

I'm given this when I chose the API Key Authentication option

```
// Authenticate via API Key
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("key");

// Make the request
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("type", "photo");
List<Post> posts = client.blogPosts("url", params);
```

There is an Example Output that is in JSON format that does not provide a URL so I'm not able to parse the JSON in the app. I'm only left with the this java code and the tutorial I'm following is using JSON [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GzVtP0IODU&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=30)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would need to create an adaptor for the recycler view.

Please note that in the code I am using picasso library for fetching the image. So be sure to include it in your gradle file.

Sample code for the Recycler View Adaptor

```
package com.sample.demo.adaptor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


public class ImagesRecyclerViewAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesRecyclerViewAdaptor.ImagesViewHolder> {

    private List<Post> posts;

    public ImagesRecyclerViewAdaptor(List<Post> _posts) {
        this.posts = _posts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImagesViewHolder imageViewHolder, int i) {
        Post ci = posts.get(i);
        if (ci != null) {

            // EXTRACT THE URL FROM POST NOT SURE WHAT FUNCTION TO USE
            Uri uri = Uri.parse();
            Context context = imageViewHolder.vPostImage.getContext();
            Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageViewHolder.vPostImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ImagesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.image_cardview, viewGroup, false);

        ImagesViewHolder viewHolder = new ImagesViewHolder(itemView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public static class ImagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        protected ImageView vPostImage;

        public ImagesViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);

            vPostImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_hotel_image);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

From you main activity or fragment call

```
// Authenticate via API Key
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient("key");

// Make the request
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("type", "photo");
List<Post> posts = client.blogPosts("url", params);

final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

RecyclerView imageList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
imageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
imageList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

ImagesRecyclerViewAdaptor imageAdaptor = new ImagesRecyclerViewAdaptor(posts);
imageList.setAdapter(imageAdaptor);
```